# Working with delay in Java

Tags: java, android, delay

I'm trying to create a speech recognition app where the app recieves voice and sends out stuff. I'd like everything that the onEndOfSpeech method to be called to wait a second and then do the entire voice recognition intent to start over again.

```
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    Log.d("Speech", "onEndOfSpeech");

         try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        }
```

Not sure that I am doing this correctly.
Thanks!

Comment: Thread.sleep(3000); is not good. Use a handler.

Comment: It's better to schedule something to occur 3000 milliseconds from now, rather than freeze the whole program for 3000 milliseconds.

Comment: I would like to do that Patashu, how would I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should be

```
try {
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // it depends on your app logic what to do with InterruptedException, you can process it or rethrow or restore interrupted flag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
protected boolean _active = true;
// time to display the splash screen in ms
protected int _splashTime = 1000;
Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
try {
int waited = 0;
while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
sleep(100);
if(_active) {
waited += 100;
}
}
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
}
```